# Best way to do a clean Miniconda install

Tags: python, anaconda, miniconda

In the past I have made a mess of my local machine installing various versions of `Anaconda` and `Miniconda` and `Jupyter Notebooks` - when I didn't really know what I was doing (I at least know a little more now).

Now I don't seem to have `ipython`, but I have `python`. `conda --help` gives and error message, but I do have some paths that mention Miniconda.

I mostly use remote machines, and so I don't code much on my laptop, but it's about time I tidied things up - is there a simple way I can wipe the slate clean and just install a new version of Miniconda and forget about everything other partial / failed / old install?

Comment: How did you install Miniconda the first time around? Have you tried downloading an installer from https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html and (re)running it?

Comment: What OS are you using?  You first want to uninstall miniconda, but instructions vary depending on OS. After reinstalling per the instructions, only set up Jupyter in your base environment. https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/index.html

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 16.04. I did try to reinstall miniconda but I got an error about a path already existing. I will try to uninstall miniconda first.